# Understanding one- vs two tailed tests from simulated data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Simulation has helped me a lot in my understanding of inferential statistics. But I have hit a roadblock and need help filling-in the gaps in my knowledge. Given test and control samples of data, I can determine the correct p-values and confidence intervals for both one- and two-tailed z-tests. Here are the steps I follow:

1. Calculate sample size, mean and standard deviation for each sample
2. Determine sampling distributions for each sample (shape = Normal, mean = sample mean, standard deviation = standard deviation of sample divided by square root of sample size)
3. Determine sampling distribution of the difference in means
4. Determine sampling distribution of the difference in means for the null hypothesis
5. Calculate p-values

**All these steps lead me to the correct p-values.**

But I want to ask *WHY* we take certain steps after step 3 above. Here is my sampling distribution of the difference in means:
[image]

**Question 1**: **Why do I need to worry about formulating my hypotheses upfront - why can't I let the data speak for itself?** If my null hypothesis is that Test and Control behave the same then I would choose a two-tailed test. If on the other hand my null hypothesis is that my chosen Test metric was either greater than or less than that in the Control then I would choose a one-tailed test.

But the data above simply tells me that ***in 99.42% of experiments the Test metric is greater than the Control metric***. So I would be confident that the Test population mean is greater than the Control population mean. The results speak for themselves, don't they? How could I conclude anything else from this data - what am I missing?

**Question 2**: **Why would my p-value double for a two-tailed test?** If my chosen null hypothesis is that both Test and Control results are the same, then I'd construct the sampling distribution of the difference in means for the null hypothesis by taking the distribution above and subtracting 2.418 from all the values. Then I'd ask "What is the probability of seeing a result as extreme or more than 2.418, assuming the null hypothesis is true."

I understand that "as extreme or more than" means >= 2.481 OR <= -2.418. BUT from the distribution above which represents actual simulated data there is practically no way that the difference is -2.418. So why would we consider this region of the chart at all?

[image]